# Why does autostart work for lubuntu 18.10 Cosmic Cuttlefish and not for 22.04.2 Jammy Jellyfish?

Tags: lubuntu, version, autostart

I have several machines in the field and many more sitting in inventory that have not been updated in a few years. **uname -a** returns the following:

```
Linux <machine 1> 4.18.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 6 18:45:52 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I re-imaged one of the machines in inventory with the latest lubuntu. **uname -a** returns the following:

```
Linux <machine 2> 5.19.0-43-generic #44~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon May 22 13:39:36 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I re-installed the application that should be run at startup and copied the desktop file into ~/.config/autostart, but it is not launching the application. This is the contents of the desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
Exec=/bin/bash -c "sleep 5 && /opt/myApp/autostart.sh"
Path=/opt/myApp/current
Name=MyApp
Comment=Application to run at startup
```

If I launch a terminal window and run **/bin/bash -c "sleep 5 && /opt/myApp/autostart.sh"** it launches the app, as I would have expected the autostart feature to do.
What has changed between these two releases so that this app no longer launches on startup and what do I need to modify? I've searched and tried several options, but nothing has worked so far.

### Update

I have found that /opt/MyApp/autostart.sh is being executed, but the application within the shell script is not being executed. I'm using PM2 to launch a nodejs script. I added a line to the shell script, **/snap/bin/firefox** and Firefox launched successfully, so the issue appears to be an incompatibility with autostart and PM2. I will look into the PM2 documentation for an alternate approach to launching on startup.

### Update 2

It turns out autostart is not needed at all. PM2 has a utility, **pm2 startup**, that tells PM2 to detect available init system, generate configuration and enable the startup system. Simple. The application now works as it did in the previous release.